# Unable to change user password

Tags: users

I have Ubuntu 12.10 and I have lost the password and the system will not allow me to delete or change the password. I've attempted to use the advance method through the Grub but all I get is an error message

> "manipulation token error"

not allowing any keystroke entries. I don't have a CD to attempt any other method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to boot a live system from USB stick. This is even possible on older machines, but with some detours.

You need another PC for that to create that bootsick. I recommend using the software UNetBootin to create a bootable stick. It's nearly self-explanatory.

If this old machine allows USB Legacy Emulation (found somewhere in the BIOS setup), enable it and try to boot from USB stick. If not, use [Plop Boot Manager](http://www.plop.at/en/bootmanagers.html) or something similar to boot from USB.

If you're able to bring up the live boot menu (UNetBootin menu, if created with UnetBootin), select *Try Ubuntu*. After the GUI finished loading, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter the following commands:

```
# List partitions to find the correct one
sudo fdisk -l
# Memorize the name of the partiton with "Linux" type and "boot" flag
# Create mount directory (replace the hdd by anything you want)
sudo mkdir /media/hdd
# Mount partition into this directory (replace XY by memorized partition file name)
sudo mount /dev/sdXY /media/hdd
# Open root shell of the installed system
sudo chroot /media/sdXY
# Change password of user and drop back to live system shell
passwd username
exit
```

Now shut down your machine, remove the bootstick and boot into the installed system. The password should be the one entered on `passwd username`.